# Insert a separator into a dropdown list in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that pulls information on tools. I have a multi-value parameter setup in SSRS that pulls a tool name and GUID and then passes the GUIDs to a stored proc for results.

The tools have in addition to name and GUID a value of active. I want to display a list of tools with active items first, then inactive. Easy enough that's just an order, however I'd like to put a visual separator between active and inactive tools. I can achieve this by creating an order value based on active status, and then using union to attach a dummy line between them.

However this means its possible to select the separator line. I can handle that line in my stored procedure so it doesn't cause a problem, but I'd like to make that line unselectable or to have a separator similar to what you see in a dropdown menu.

Does anyone know of any functionality that will achieve this?

I main project is currently help in 2008R2, but I may be able to upgrade if there is a good solution to this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is creating a Parameter for Active and Inactive, that then populates the Tool Name Parameter.

Comment: Hi newGuy. yeah this was one of the approaches that I considered. However when multi select is enabled, you cannot have NULL, so you'd need to add two dummy values, one onto each parameter, and then filter out both.  Good to see that other people think the same way that I do though.

Comment: You can have NULLS in Multiselects, check this out. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3502/allow-null-value-in-multi-value-report-parameter-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

OK - have found there seems to be no way of showing a separator as such short of coding in a separator line in the data set. Final solution was close to my original plan. I now download two datasets, one of all tools (Active, separator, inactive) and attach this to my available values, and one of active only, which I then attach to my default values.

This means that both are available, but default is active only. Not a solution to the exact question, but best that I could come up with and is close enough to fit for purpose.

If anyone does come across better solutions, I'd love to here them.